# How do I display directly a XAML page on a new window in C#, that will be opened as soon as I'm authenticated?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've recently started a highschool project and I want to display a page.

I use an API to connect. Once I'm logged in, it opens a new window (ShellWindow.xaml file). This is where I want a page to appear directly. I tried a way to set the default display of a page but it didn't work, I can't find a solution.

Here's my code:

AuthenticateWindow.xaml.cs :

```
private void btn_signin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String message = Login.Connect(tbx_email.Text, pbx_pwd.Password);
        if (message == "Success")
        {
            // Call the ShellWindow view and close without verifying the credentials : TODO
            ShellWindow mainWindow = new ShellWindow();
            mainWindow.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            // Set the message for the user
            tbx_message.Text = message;
        }
    }
```

ShellWindow.xaml :

```
<mah:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
        <mah:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>

            <mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem IsEnabled="True"  Glyph="Car" Label="Gestion des véhicules">
                <mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                    <views:VehicleManagementView IsEnabled="True"/>
                </mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
            </mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>
            
            <mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="Book" Label="Tableau de bord">
                <mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                    <views:BookingView/>
                </mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
            </mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>

            <mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="ChartAreaspline" Label="Statistiques">
                <mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                    <views:StatBookingView/>
                </mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
            </mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>

            <mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="Head" Label="Profil">
                <mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                    <views:AboutView/>
                </mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
            </mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>
            
            <mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="Head" Label="Véhicule Info">
                <mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                    <views:VehicleInfo/>
                </mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
            </mah:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>

        </mah:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
    </mah:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
```

Comment: It didn't work in what way?  When you are calling "this.Close" is it stopping the whole application?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If your `ShellWindow.xaml` looks like this, it's no wonder that your views are not displayed. Setting the item source is one thing, but besides this, you need lots of other things to make it work.

First, you need to import the namespace, which I suppose you did, but for the sake of clarity:

```
xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
```

Then you have to specify templates for your items, to make them look like the way you saw them on the mahapps metro examples (or the way you want them to). You can specify this in `ShellWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem}">
            <Grid Height="48">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                    FontSize="16"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Text="{Binding Glyph}" />
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="16"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Text="{Binding Label}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Now, you can add the `HamburgerMenu` control, set an event for the selected item (`ItemInvoked`), set the data template of your items (`ItemTemplate` and `OptionsItemTemplate`), specify the template for the content (`<controls:HamburgerMenu.ContentTemplate>`) and add the items:

```
<controls:HamburgerMenu
        x:Name="HamburgerMenuControl"
        DisplayMode="CompactInline"
        Foreground="White"
        IsPaneOpen="False"
        ItemInvoked="HamburgerMenuControl_OnItemInvoked"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"
        OptionsItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}">

        <!--  Items  -->
        <controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
            <controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
                <controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="" Label="Home">
                    <controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                        <views:VehicleManagementView />
                    </controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                </controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>

                <!-- Same goes for the other views. -->
                
            </controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
        </controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>

        <!--  Options  -->
        <controls:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>
            <controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
                <controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="" Label="Settings">
                    <!-- Same as in the items above. -->
                </controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>
            </controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
        </controls:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>

        <!--  Content  -->
        <controls:HamburgerMenu.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type controls:HamburgerMenuItem}">
                <Grid x:Name="TheContentGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="48" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF444444">
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="Header"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            FontSize="24"
                            Foreground="White"
                            Text="{Binding Label}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ContentControl
                        x:Name="TheContent"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Content="{Binding Tag}"
                        Focusable="False"
                        Foreground="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:HamburgerMenu.ContentTemplate>
    </controls:HamburgerMenu>
```

Lastly, in your `ShellWindow.xaml.cs` create the method for the item clicked event:

```
private void HamburgerMenuControl_OnItemInvoked(object sender, HamburgerMenuItemInvokedEventArgs e)
{
    this.HamburgerMenuControl.Content = e.InvokedItem;

    if (!e.IsItemOptions && this.HamburgerMenuControl.IsPaneOpen)
    {
        // You can close the menu if an item was selected
        // this.HamburgerMenuControl.SetCurrentValue(HamburgerMenuControl.IsPaneOpenProperty, false);
    }
}
```

For more detail about [mahapps hamburger menus](https://mahapps.com/docs/controls/HamburgerMenu).